# Exclude files from "Messages Code Analysis" inspections? Tried scope, isn't working

Tags: webstorm

So I'm having trouble with WebStorm giving me all kinds of warnings with libraries like bootstrap.  I obviously don't care about these.  After some googling, I thought defining a project "scope" would fix the issue.  I did that, but still receive the messages.  I have closed and reopened the IDE.  Below are screenshots of the messages and my defined scope (which clearly does not include the files showing up in warnings).

**Updated:** Added a third picture that shows the message I get when I commit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you run code analysis? `Code | Inspect Code...`? If so -- it has "Scope" option -- have you selected your scope there?

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not manually triggering any type of inspection.  These just show up in the "messages" window.  It also shows me a summary when I try to commit.  If I manually trigger an inspection I get different results.  I don't know, maybe I'm just doing something totally weird...

Comment: There should be an option in Commit to VCS screen to execute Code Analysis. Check there (I do not use VCS (unfortunately :( ) so cannot help here) -- it may have an option what scope to use (but you should be able to disable it for sure). At very least I would expect Code Analysis to not to run on not-about-to-commit files...

Comment: I think I figured it out, will explain in an answer with screenshots.

Comment: There is no way to choose scope when running inspections from Commit view, but scopes chosen for inspections in Settings/Inspections seem to work here - i.e. though the scope for code analysis run on commit is 'changed files', it's additionally filtered by inspection own scopes. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-inspection-for-different-scopes.html for more info on inspection scopes

Answer (score 0):

Okay, LONG story short, I had to open File > Settings > Inspections.  I then had to add my scope to **each** top-level item I cared about (CSS, Javascript, HTML, General, etc).

When you do that, it adds entries like the following:

[image]

As you can see, when you add it it keeps "Everything else" checked...  So I had to go through and uncheck everything then manually check (dozens and dozens) of "In scope 'NoLib'" checkboxes.

Now I *finally* don't get messages for the files I don't care about.

Comment: I feel like I must have done something wrong but I have no idea what it would have been... this is way to complicated.